# Chart.js Bar Widths Changing When Updating Data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

Using Chart.js 2.7.2, I'm updating a single dataset when a table is filtered to graph the data displayed in the filtered table in the following chart:

```
volumeChart = new Chart(volume, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labelList,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: volumeDataSet
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          source: 'labels',
          beginAtZero: false
        },
        bounds: 'labels',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        categoryPercentage: 0.5,
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        offset: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

The data updates fine, but the displayed bars have different widths and spacing depending on the dataset.

[Here is how the chart displays when the data is not filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiyg3.png)

[Here is how it displays when it is filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33yDb.png)

All I am doing upon filtering is creating a new array of data from the filtered results, and replacing the dataset like so:

```
volumeChart.data.datasets[0].data = volumeDataSet;
```

Then updating the chart like so:

```
volumeChart.update();
```

Comment: What is the behaviour when `maintainAspectRatio: true`?

Comment: No change, unfortunately. I've disabled that to allow me to set a fixed height.